# Change input value on Button Click

Tags: jquery

I am trying to check if an input number field has a specific value and if so, change it to another value. This is my code:

```
<html>
    <div id="container">
        <input class="column10" type="number" value="0">
        <button class="calculate-button">Calculate</button>
    </div>
</html>

<script>
jQuery('calculate-button').on('click', '.column10', function(){
  if(this.value == 9)
  {
    this.value=1.5;
    jQuery(this).change();
  }
});
</script>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/gatw902b/

But I can't get it to work. Can somebody help me?
Thanks!

Comment: What you are tying to do? On button click you want to set value for the text box as 1.5? you cannot get text box value by using `this.value` in button change. `this` points to the current object

Comment: On button click I want to check if the input box has the value 9 and if it has this value change it to 1.5. If not, do nothing. I am using input type="number", not text?

Comment: check below solution @timo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `.` operator for using a class selector as `$('.calculate-button')` and another mistake is use of `this`. `this` inside the change function of button will check for the button value,not the textbox value. for that you have to take values with selector as `$('.column10').val()`

```js
$('.calculate-button').on('click',function(){
$(".column10").each(function(){
        if($(this).val()==9){
            $(this).val(1.5);
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
    <div id="container">
        <input class="column10" type="number" value="0">
        <input class="column10" type="number" value="0">
        <input class="column10" type="number" value="0">
        
        <button class="calculate-button">Calculate</button>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, it generally works. But, if I add more than one input field it only works for the first one and if fill in different numbers it changes all input fields to 1.5 if one value is equal to 9. I want to only change the values 9 to 1.5 and no other input fields. See: jsfiddle.net/myuv0fbx

Comment: @TimodeVries check now

Answer (score 0):

There are various problems in your code.

```
jQuery('calculate-button').on('click', '.column10', function(){
```

First you did not use the right selector, it should have been ".calculate-button".

Then you used ".on" event on the button, but checking click on ".column10" which is not a child of the button, so it would never trigger.

This is the right code:

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '.calculate-button', function(){
  var oInput = jQuery('#container input[type=number]');
  if( jQuery(oInput).val() == 9 )
  {
    jQuery(oInput).val(1.5)
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, it generally works. But, if I add more than one input field it only works for the first one and if  fill in different numbers it changes all input fields to 1.5 if one value is equal to 9. I want to only change the values 9 to 1.5 and no other input fields. See: https://jsfiddle.net/myuv0fbx/

Answer (score 0):

Here I've made some changes in your code. I hope it's helpful for you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="container">
            <input class="column10" type="number">
            <button class="calculate-button">Calculate</button>
        </div>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.slim.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            jQuery('.calculate-button').on('click', function(){
                var inputVal = jQuery('.column10');
                if (inputVal.val() == 10) {
                    inputVal.val(20);
                }
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

First problem is you missed . operator

```
    $('.calculate-button').on('click',function(){
    $(".column10").each(function(){
        if($(this).val() === 9){
            $(this).val(1.5);
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not select the button to click on and use the jquery .val() instead of .value

```
jQuery('body').on('click', '.calculate-button', function(){
   console.log('res cat');
   if($('.column10').val() == 9){
      $('.column10').val(1.5);
      jQuery($('.column10')).change();
    }
```

});